# VBA code for read an Excel file

Tags: vba

I want to make an excel file read using a VBA code in a simulation software. Please let me know how can I do this?

Comment: You will need to provide some more details.  What in the file do you want to read?  What sort of 'simulation software'?  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

A very basic outline would be:

```
Dim xlApp As Object
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

xlApp.Workbooks.Open "C:\foo.xls"

' do stuff here

xlApp.Quit
Set xlApp = Nothing
```

Depending on what you actually want to achieve you may want to consider:

- saving an Excel worksheet as a CSV
  (comma separated value) file and
  reading directly from the CSV file
- using ADO to treat an Excel worksheet
  as a database table so that you can
  use SQL to read from it